# Setting up GIT and workflow for bigger web based application

Tags: git, version-control

We have a biggish internal web based system that currently is maintained by a team of 3 developers.
Our current setup is 1 development server and 1 production server - possibly soon 2 prodution servers behind load balancer.
Our current workflow is all developers update files live on dev server. Whenever we are ready with the changes we rsync codebase to production.
We develop fast and change things very often. For quite some time we've been wanting to start using version control to have more control over the changes we make and the overall code quality. The only question is how to do it properly and 
what would be the most efficient way since we still have to keep things moving fast.

Some of the question I have are:

- Our main codebase contains directories with 3rd party libraries, images etc. We rarely touch them. Should these be tracked as well?
- Is it ok to have just one master branch to work on? So every dev would use master branch that will be pulled to Main Dev and then to Production.
- Should production be setup as bare repo or it doesn't matter?

Here's the setup I came up with. Please let me know what you think and suggest improvements.
[image]

Comment: you don't need a subdomain per developer... you can do local and svn to dev. Otherwise is good. I would include 3rd party libraries and stuff into the repo. If not, you will overburden the lead developer with updating libraries and stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The idea is that all developers will change and most importantly test their code on the same development server rather than locally to make things simpler.

Comment: That would include an element of unpredictability that you might not want. Two developers might be working on the same class or one may be using something that the other is modifying...

Comment: Well, DEV 1, DEV 2, DEV 3 would be separate repos for each developer cloned from MAIN DEV so everybody would be touching only their own code.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Horrer] all developers update files live on dev server. No source control

At'a Boy to you for fixing your architecture and workflow. I was in this exact situation in a long ago job.

- Yes, you should definitely checkin your 3rd party libraries, images etc. You rarely touch them because the world comes to a crashing end if you update them. You can't bring a second production server online unless you can build it exactly like the first one. Every thing need to be running the same version of all the same software. In my project we had everything that got installed on the server in source control.
- Yes it's ok to just use master, you don't want to change too many moving parts at one time. As time goes bye revisit this to see if your ready / need a branching workflow.
- You can't use a bare repo. There would be no files for the web server to run off of.

Great job, good questions and design.

I would definitely use sub domains for each developer. Another place I worked at, a commercial software company, wicked smart people, did it this way.

My one suggestion would be to have stage.project.com running on the Production server. It would use the production data sources and let you test in a production environment.

Also everyone on the Team should have to watch. Git ages 4 and up http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4 and for extra credit watch Advanced Git http://vimeo.com/37408017

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said "stage.project.com running on the Production server". Great suggestion. It just reminded me that we can make it so when people in our office are accessing the website staging copy will be served silently instead of production copy. This way we will be able to discover new bugs quicker and before they reach production copy and the customer in the end :)

Comment: Also everyone on the Team should have to watch. Git ages 4 and up http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4 and for extra credit watch Advanced Git http://vimeo.com/37408017

Answer (score 1):

What I don't like about your plan is the deployment stage. Why? Because 1) it's a manual process and 2) it's pull-based. I'm also not sure what I think about version control repositories on a production server.

What I would like to suggest is to build a little script that `rsync`s to the production servers, including rsync's `--delete` and `--exclude .git/` options. If you wanted, you could write the SHA1 of the current commit to a little file so you can always know what is online.

Ideally, that script wouldn't sync directly to your document-root, but to a freshly created directory that you then symlink your document-root to. Name that directory using a timestamp and maybe the commit SHA-1. That way, if anything doesn't work out the way it was supposed to, you just have to adjust the target of your symlink.

Comment: I like your suggestions. So I would rsync to new location which would become staging copy and then when we're ready we would point production link at staging leaving original production copy hanging around until next staging copy arrives? Basically production server would always have two rolling copies of the source code. Did I get it right?

Comment: Absolutely right. Yes. But why stop at two copies? Storage is cheap, so why not ten? Or a hundred?

Comment: I agree that a package and deploy workflow is much preferred but this organization is used to editing files directly on the web server. Having it be a checkout lets you tell if some one did that. Also if the Stuff hits the fan a quick fix in production can be committed and pushed back up stream.

Comment: GayleDDS: Yes, these are the obvious benefits. However, I'd like to never find myself in a situation where I have to solve merge conflicts in a production environment.